# Check whether child records exist for parent records query taking long time

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization

I need to retrieve all the parent records which have corresponding records existing child table. In my script I have created on column `ISTopicMapping` exist which stores 1 if child record exist for specific parent record, if not then we are setting 0 in that field.

To achieve the same in have used CASE statement with sub query which is taking 32 sec. to execute.

This is my script:

```
;WITH CTE_Topics AS 
(
    SELECT 
        TermId, Term, ParentId 
    FROM 
        Terms WITH (NOLOCK) 
    WHERE 
        ParentId = 24 AND IsDeleted = 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        T.TermId, T.Term, T.ParentId 
    FROM 
        Terms T WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN 
        CTE_Topics CT ON T.ParentId = CT.TermId AND T.IsDeleted = 0
),
CTE_Filter AS 
(
    SELECT TermId 
    FROM CTE_Topics WITH (NOLOCK) 
    WHERE Term IN ('Topis 1', 'Topis 2', 'Topis 3', 'Topis 4', 'Topis 5', )
)
, CTE_AR AS
(
    SELECT 
        TermId, Term, ParentId, LongDescription 
    FROM 
        TermMappings TM WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN 
        Terms TD WITH (NOLOCK) ON TD.TermId = TM.DestinationId 
                               AND TD.IsDeleted = 0 
                               AND TM.IsDeleted = 0 
                               AND TM.SourceId = 5121
                               AND TD.ParentId IN (100, 108)
)
, CTE_AOC AS
(
    SELECT 
        TermId, Term, ParentId, LongDescription 
    FROM 
        TermMappings TM WITH(NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN 
        Terms TD WITH(NOLOCK) ON TD.TermId = TM.DestinationId 
                              AND TD.IsDeleted = 0  
                              AND TM.IsDeleted = 0 
                              AND TM.SourceId = 5300
                              AND TD.ParentId IN (100, 108)
    WHERE 
        TermId NOT IN (SELECT TermId FROM CTE_AR)
)
, CTE_Result AS
(
    SELECT 
        TermId,
        Term,
        ParentId,
        LongDescription,
        CASE 
            WHEN (SELECT COUNT(1) 
                  FROM TermMappings WITH(NOLOCK)
                  WHERE SourceId = TermId 
                    AND DestinationId IN (SELECT TermId FROM CTE_Filter) 
                    AND IsDeleted = 0) > 0 
               THEN 1 
               ELSE 0 
        END AS TopicMappingExist
    FROM 
        CTE_AOC 
)
SELECT * 
FROM CTE_Result 
WHERE TopicMappingExist = 1
```

I have observe that CASE statement taking long time to execute which is slowing down the query. can any one suggest solution to address the issue.

Comment: You've been told about this before, but just a reminder: [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere) You clearly don't understand the hint as you do things like use `NOLOCK` against the table `Terms` in the CTE `CTE_Topics`, but then go and use the hint *again* against the CTE `CTE_Topics`; all the tables in `CTE_Topics` already have `NOLOCK` against them, so why define it again? If you "must" (you don't) (mis)use that hint everywhere, why are you not changing the isolation level of the transaction instead?

Comment: @Larnu - thanks for pointing out. i realised and removed against all CTEs.

Comment: I was actually saying you should remove it **everywhere**.

Comment: @Larnu - sure let me try this as well. thanks

Comment: Inside the `CASE` statement you are using subquery; this means that your query will run once for each row. Change your business logic in your query, use join or another ways do it.